# Excel Data Validation on Save/Close

Tags: validation, vba, excel

I have a standard Excel sheet with 10 columns:

For example, a user can fill up to 100 rows. I want to write a macro/validation such that all 10 columns will be filled for each row.

I need the approach to do show an alert to the user when the user saves/closes the sheet.

Comment: What do you have so far?  If you show that we can suggest changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most basic of ideas. You should be able to expand on this, then use some workbook events to call this macro on saving and/or closing.

```
Sub ValidateData()
Dim ws As Worksheet, Rw As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")       'the sheet to analyze

For Rw = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(Rw)) <> 0 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(Rw)) < 10 Then
            ws.Activate
            ws.Range("A" & Rw).Resize(, 10).Select
            MsgBox "This row is incomplete"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next Rw

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution has a few flaws. First, it will make the message box pop up several times (assuming multiple empty cells), and the message doesn't display which row is incomplete. Also, it's based off `UsedRange` rather than the 10x100 range, so if they only filled the first 5 rows, then it would completely ignore the rows below. The loop and use of `Select` and `Activate` are inefficient, as well. A better method might use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` of the 10x100 area and display that range in a messagebox. I believe this only catches blanks up to `xlLastCell` in a given range.

Comment: @Zairja, I think you might be having a "gut reaction" to seeing "Select" in a macro, which is typically bad.  In this instance, the macro "activates" the sheet where the problem exists and SELECTS the problem row prior to the MsgBox (which should only appear once and then aborts the macro).  Once on that sheet and being presented one incomplete row, logic would dictate the user would complete any other incomplete rows, too, else it would present another SINGLE msgbox until they got the idea "Hey, I need to fix all of these".  The OP could certainly edit the macro For Rw = 1 To 100.

Comment: +1. You're right. I didn't look closely enough at your macro. However, I'm not sure why you choose to check if `CountA <> 0` since that would indicate an entirely blank row and the OP wanted all 10 columns filled for each row (so you would want to flag an entirely empty row). Also, if the `UsedRange` happens to start below the first row (say the first 8 rows were empty), then `Rw` would need to be offset, as well.

Comment: I was only wanting to evaluate incomplete rows, not rows with NOTHING, meaning not used at all yet.  If they had only filled a cell or two, it would flag that row.  And again, the OP can certainly refine the **For Rw = 10 to 100** or something like that, if they wish.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone out there since the OP is long gone. You can change the range to `A1:J1000` or whatever cells you need. This assumes you're calling it from the Worksheet level. Otherwise, you may need to explicitly reference the ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Validater()

Dim r As Range
Dim numBlanks As Integer

Set r = Range("A1:E10")

numBlanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r)

If numBlanks > 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are " & numBlanks & " empty cells."
End If

End Sub
```